# Split a span list into multiple horizontal table using CSS - is it possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a large html file containing multiple span elements. The contents of the file I can't control as it has been given to me.

I am trying to place the contents of the elements in the span element into horizontal boxes every time the class='entity' is shown. I can only use CSS to do this.

Is this possible or not worth investigating?

For example:

```
| Payment         | Vendor          |
| Type of Payment | Type Of Card    |
| Type            | Type            |
```

```html
<span class='entity'>payment</span>
<span class='stage'>Type Of Payment</span>
<span class='desc'>Type</span>
<span class='control'>type</span>
<span class='desc'>Primary Customer</span>
<span class='control'>customer</span>
<span class='id'>ConditionBranchStep445</span>
<span class='desc'>Leaseholder</span>
<span class='stageid'>4decd3c7-4bd4-3149-428c-ab2613eac80a</span>
<span class='parentstage'>87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f</span>
<span class='id'>ConditionBranchStep447</span>
<span class='desc'>General Payment</span>

<span class='entity'>Vendor</span>
<span class='stage'>Type Of Card</span>
<span class='desc'>Type</span>
<span class='control'>type</span>
<span class='desc'>Secondary Customer</span>
<span class='control'>customer</span>
<span class='id'>ConditionBranchStep445</span>
<span class='desc'>Leaseholder</span>
<span class='stageid'>4decd3c7-4bd4-3149-428c-ab2613eac80a</span>
<span class='parentstage'>87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f</span>
<span class='id'>ConditionBranchStep447</span>
<span class='desc'>General Payment</span>
```

Comment: Is this an accurate list with persistent classes? Or may the list be different?

Comment: This is an accurate list that is repeated with the same classes.

Comment: It looks from the example of layout you have given as though you want each 'entity' to be in a column, with the columns next to each other horizontally (I assume until the page width is reached and then to start another 'row'). Is that right? How tabular-looking is it to be, for example what if one entry has a lot of text?

Comment: That's exactly what I am hoping for; the page width doesn't matter. It can stretch beyond the viewport.

Comment: @sy-huss, like that? - https://ibb.co/Fzswm8Q

Comment: Thanks for trying this; Payment should be at the top of the box/column, with General Payment at the end. Then the next column begins at Vendor and ends at General Payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the values, I advise you to use a **grid** display, in conjunction with the `grid-auto-flow: dense` rule, which allows you to place rows one by one.

In my solution, I used the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class to target the *first 12* - `:nth-child(-n + 12)` and the *second 12* - `:nth-child(n + 13)` span, split into two columns, using rule `grid-column: n`.

```css
div {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    gap: 10px;
}

div span:nth-child(-n + 12) {
    grid-column: 1;
}

div span:nth-child(n + 13) {
    grid-column: 2;
}

div span {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="entity">payment</span>
    <span class="stage">Type Of Payment</span>
    <span class="desc">Type</span>
    <span class="control">type</span>
    <span class="desc">Primary Customer</span>
    <span class="control">customer</span>
    <span class="id">ConditionBranchStep445</span>
    <span class="desc">Leaseholder</span>
    <span class="stageid">4decd3c7-4bd4-3149-428c-ab2613eac80a</span>
    <span class="parentstage">87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f</span>
    <span class="id">ConditionBranchStep447</span>
    <span class="desc">General Payment</span>

    <span class="entity">Vendor</span>
    <span class="stage">Type Of Card</span>
    <span class="desc">Type</span>
    <span class="control">type</span>
    <span class="desc">Secondary Customer</span>
    <span class="control">customer</span>
    <span class="id">ConditionBranchStep445</span>
    <span class="desc">Leaseholder</span>
    <span class="stageid">4decd3c7-4bd4-3149-428c-ab2613eac80a</span>
    <span class="parentstage">87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f</span>
    <span class="id">ConditionBranchStep447</span>
    <span class="desc">General Payment</span>
</div>
```